# How to add Recaptcha in login from?

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

How to add Recaptcha in login form? My code is:

```
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="post">
        <input type=hidden name=menu value=login>
        User Id: <br><input class="inp" type="text" name="uNev"><br>
        Password: <br><input class="inp" type="password" name="uJelszo">
                  <p align="center"><input class="inp" type="submit" name="uLogin" value="Log-In" id="button">
    </form>
```

I will try **recaptcha-php-1.11** but don't know how to do it, please help me.

Comment: http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha

Comment: yes documentation isn't enough pleas help i will try

Comment: I can't believe they closed this question

Answer (score 3):

You can Use google recaptcha for this.Google captcha is best for security point of views. Its also provide audio captcha. Its very easy to use.
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha

Comment: don't know how to use the code.

Comment: No Issue...Goto this link http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha
Sign up with your gmail account.
Place your website address
Now google provide PHP code for captcha.

Comment: If u r using any framework than create helper or component for this.

Comment: yeah framework like codeigniter this is a good one very simple: https://github.com/ollierattue/codeigniter-recaptcha

Answer (score 0):

1) Download the recaptcha library from here https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/detail?name=recaptcha-php-1.11.zip&can=2&q=label%3Aphplib-Latest

2) Extract it and copy the `recaptchalib.php` file into the directory where your form file resides.

3) Signup for recaptcha here http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha

4) Copy the public key and paste it in the right place into your form file that must look something like this:

```
<html>
<body> <!-- the body tag is required or the CAPTCHA may not show on some browsers -->
  <!-- your HTML content -->

  <form method="post" action="verify.php">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name"> <br>
    Email: <input type="email" name="email">
    <?php
      require_once('recaptchalib.php');
      $publickey = "your public key here"; // you got this from the signup page
      echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    ?>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>

  <!-- more of your HTML content -->
</body>
</html>
```

5) Then create another file, verify.php that must also resides with your form and recaptchalib.php files.

```
 <?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "your private key here";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
    echo "Success!";
  }
  ?>
```

6) From the page where you got the public key, now copy the private key and paste it in the right place in the `verify.php` file.